# Filter search results react

Tags: html, reactjs

My data back from search result has columns: enTitle,Image,url,enDescription,HasLandingPage,AddInfo.

I want to filter search results by AddInfo to show in different lists. later if I can add a button that would be better.

Render Data:

```
const ListArticle = (props) =>{
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="search-img-lft">
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                    <img src={props.image} alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="search-imgcont-rgt">
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                    <h3>
                        {props.title}
                        {props.kind} // just to see if kind works
                    </h3>
                    <p>{props.desc}</p>
                </a>
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank" className="default-link">{props.link}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

List Class:(ignore the i,brac & lim they are for pagination)

```
    class List extends React.Component {
        render(){
            const liArt =[];
            const searchText = this.props.searchText.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
            var i = 0;
            const brac = this.props.start;
            const lim = brac + this.props.qtyPerPage;
//the filter below works for resources but I want all to be filtered and show in the list in previous code snippet
                this.props.list.filter(u=>u.AddInfo == "resource").map((article)=>{
                        var artText = (article.enTitle + " " + article.URL + " " + article.enDescription + " " + article.AddInfo).toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
                        if(artText.indexOf(searchText)===-1){
                            return;
                        }
                        i++;
                        if(brac<i && i<lim){
                            liArt.push(
                                    <ListArticle key={article.Image+article.URL} 
                                        title={article.enTitle}
                                        image={article.Image+"?h=100&mode=crop&scale=down"}
                                        link={JSON.stringify(article.HasLandingPage).toUpperCase()=="TRUE" ? "/en/"+article.URL : "/" + article.URL}
                                        desc={article.enDescription}
                                        kind={article.AddInfo.includes("SKU") ? " Product" : (article.AddInfo.includes("resource") ? " Resource" : " Page")} />
                            );//push
                        } //limit check  
                });//map
            return (
                <div className="search-page-listbox">
                    {liArt}
                </div>
                );
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what errors you're getting or what the issue is? Or put your code in a demo somehow so we can see the issue(s)?

Comment: there is no errors I just dont know how to filter the results. In the second snippet I filter with one condition(AddInfo == "resource") and it work. If I remove that filter it will show all the search result. But I want the data to be seperated based on the AddInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got you right, you want to create multiple lists while each list shows items of another"AddInfo".

First, I would recommend to separate your task into three components (instead of two):
First component is the ListArticle which will be the list item, 
Second will be the component List -> that will receive the list you want to show (after they have been filtered),
Last component will be ListContainer -> this one will hold multiple lists (as many as the options of AddInfo).

Then, in ListContainer you can go over all unique AddInfo, and create List component for every option - passing only filtered items:

ListArticle.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ListArticle = (props) =>{
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="search-img-lft">
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                    <img src={props.image} alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="search-imgcont-rgt">
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                    <h3>
                        {props.title}
                        {props.kind} // just to see if kind works
                    </h3>
                    <p>{props.desc}</p>
                </a>
                <a href={props.link} target="_blank" className="default-link">{props.link}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ListArticle;
```

List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ListArticle from './ListArticle';

export default class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.list.map(article => <ListArticle key={article.Image + article.URL}
                title={article.enTitle}
                image={article.Image + "?h=100&mode=crop&scale=down"}
                link={JSON.stringify(article.HasLandingPage).toUpperCase() == "TRUE" ? "/en/" + article.URL : "/" + article.URL}
                desc={article.enDescription}
                kind={article.AddInfo.includes("SKU") ? " Product" : (article.AddInfo.includes("resource") ? " Resource" : " Page")} />
            )
        )
    }
}
```

ListContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './List';


class ListContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        let lists = {};
        let searchText = this.props.searchText;
        if(this.props){
            let filteredList = this.props.list.filter(article=>(article.enTitle + " " + article.URL + " " + article.enDescription + " " + article.AddInfo).toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '').indexOf(searchText)!==-1);
            filteredList && filteredList.forEach(u => {
                if(lists[u.AddInfo]===undefined) lists[u.AddInfo]=[];
                lists[u.AddInfo].push(u);
            });
        }

        return(
            Object.keys(lists).map(function(key, index) {
                return <List list={lists[key]} />
             })
        )
    }
}

export default ListContainer;
```

Usage:

```
<ListContainer list={list} searchText={searchText} />
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: @EvikGhazarian You're welcome. In general, it is always recommended to keep React components as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd return something like this from your `List` class (I tried explaining my thought process in comments inside the code):

```
return (<React.Fragment>
    {
        // second (kinda), I'd convert the inside generated collection (object) into an array
        // -> where the array elements are now ["AddInfo type", [array of elements with that type]] 
        Object.entries(
            // first, convert the list into an object, collecting each type of "AddInfo" into
            // -> a unique property, and storing all objects w/ that type in an array
            this.props.list.reduce((output, u) => {
                if (!output[u.AddInfo]) output[u.AddInfo] = [];
                output[u.AddInfo].push(u);
                return output
            }, {})
        )
        // third, I'd map the new array of ["AddInfo type", [array of elements with that type]] into 
        // -> the jsx output you want, like this:
        .map(([type, array]) => {
            return <div className="search-page-listbox">
                {array.map((article, i) => {
                    // ... everything inside your ".map((article...)" function can go here
                })}
            </div>
        })
    }
</React.Fragment>)
```

A few notes:

1. You can replace `var i = 0` and `i++` lines with the `i` index that automatically comes from the second parameter in the `map` function (see my version of `array.map((article, i) => ...`)
2. If you haven't seen things like array destructuring (ex: `.map(([type, array]) => ...)`) let me know, I can explain. It's a pretty shnazzy thing you can do to save some lines.
3. My first step was to figure out how to create an object container which holds sorted data based on `AddInfo` - that's why my `// first` comment comes technically after the `// second` comment. Hope that makes sense.
4. Let me know if you have questions or if there was a typeo that's breaking my code. I haven't tested it obviously since I don't have your react code / variables.